# How can I minimize/minify an XML document in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have an AS3 generated XML object that I would like to "minimize" or "minify" before I send it across the wire to a remote system.

I have been unable to locate anything in the AS3 documentation to take care of this. I debated about a regex replace... but it's a terrible solution prone to a million errors.

Does anyone have any alternatives to suggest?

**Example (Raw):**

```
trace(xml.toString());

<Foo>
    <Bar>
        <Property>Property One</Property>
        <Value />
    </Bar>
    <Bar>
        <Property>Property Two</Property>
        <Value>Value Two</Value>
    </Bar>
    ...
    ...
</Foo>
```

**Example (Desired):**

```
trace(minify(xml.toString()));

<Foo><Bar><Property>Property One</Property><Value /></Bar><Bar><Property>Property Two</Property><Value>Value Two</Value></Bar>...</Foo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the spacing characters use [`prettyPrinting = false`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#prettyPrinting):

```
XML.prettyPrinting = false;
trace(xml.toXMLString());
XML.prettyPrinting = true;
```

Comment: I can't find that in any AS3 documentation or typeahead in FlashBuilder... can you point me at some documentation on this?

Comment: [`prettyPrinting = false`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#prettyPrinting) is a link to the docs. ;)

Comment: Ohhhhhhh - it's a static property on the XML class. Got it. I was looking for it an instance property on xml object. Fantastic - thanks for the help!

Comment: You sholud better add content-encoding to HTTP requests. Disabling pretty printing won't save you a lot of traffic. XML is a text format, so it can be compressed rawly up to 10% of original size.

Comment: You could also experiment with ByteArray, it allows you to compress your data with standard compression algorithms. If your remote system supports it it can save you additional space.